# Number of permutations for hiring mr.X

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Let be $9$ candidates for a job hiring (*mr.X included*). There are $3$ judges. Every judge defines a priority list ($1st-9th$) for the candidates (1st being the best and 9th the worst). A candidate is being hired only if they exist in the first $3$ spots of each of the three lists. In how many cases is mr.X being hired?

I am thinking that for each judge there are :

$ (9-1)! * 3 $

permutations (cases) for mr.X to be hired. Given the above, then for all three judges it is:

$(8!*3)^3$

cases.

But that seems like extremely many cases.

Comment: But they do not seem that many if you consider the probability of being hired:
$1/27\sim 0.03$ Your solution seems correct to me.

Comment: That is a lot of cases, about $1.77\times 10^{15}$, but the total number of possible cases is even bigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes correct.  The probability to be in the first 3 positions on 9 total is $\frac{3}{9}=\frac{1}{3}$

Then with 3 judges the probability is $(\frac{1}{3})^3$